# Abstract form or form composition in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form:

```
class RideForm(forms.Form):
    # a lot of field
    # fields accorded to geography
    # fields accorded to condition

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # clean of all fields
```

and I want to split it like this(it is only a concept, i write this only for illustration of idea). :

```
class RideGeographyPartForm(...):

    # fields accorded to geography

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # clean only geography group of field

class RideConditionPartForm(...):

    # fields accorded to condition

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # clean only geography group of field


class RideForm(RideGeographyPartForm, RideConditionPartForm, forms.Form):


    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # this should internaly call all clean logic from
        # RideGeographyPartForm, RideConditionPartForm
```

I don't now how exactly do that. I tried to use mixin but have some problems with field initialization and should juggle with calling of internal methods. 
Something similar I can do with models using abstract Models [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) . It there a way to do this kind of composition but with forms?

Answer (score 4):

Multiple Inheritance won't do what you want, if they all implement clean(), only the first mixin clean() will be called. How about simple polymorphism?

```
class RideForm(RideConditionPartForm):

    def clean():
        super clean()
        #other stuff

class RideConditionPartForm(RideGeographyPartForm):
   def clean():
     super clean()
     #other stuff
```

Comment: :+1: I use this solution now, but maybe somebody know more declarative way to do that